What is the difference between node:crypto and crypto?
I want to use the randomUUID function from node:crypto module but I can import it in two ways, either:
import { randomUUID } from 'crypto'

or:
import { randomUUID } from 'node:crypto'

What is the difference between the two imports? I know that Node.js can be built without including support for the node:crypto module but it does not help me much in understanding the difference.

(Keyword that finally let me find a dupe: Node protocol import.)

Per the documentation:

node: URLs are supported as an alternative means to load Node.js
builtin modules. This URL scheme allows for builtin modules to be
referenced by valid absolute URL strings.
import fs from 'node:fs/promises';


They've been supported by import since v12.20.0/v14.13.1, and by require since v14.18.0/v16.0.0.
Note that while most builtin modules are available either with or without the prefix, some newer modules (like node:test) are accessible only via the prefixed name. I try to consistently use the prefixes whenever using Node.js modules so it's clear that they're builtin rather than third party.

Interesting, since node.js can come without built-in crypto I am wondering is it safe to use randomUUID package inside my library?

Safe compared to what? You could handle the error (see https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#determining-if-crypto-support-is-unavailable) and fallback to a third-party implementation, e.g. CryptoJS

Okay, so I have a package where I am using the external dependency uuid for generating random strings. I decided to replace this external dependency with the function randomUUID. And now I am wondering is it breaking change for my users. But I have never met the case where someone was using node without the node:crypto

If that is a concern that you want to support, again you can provide it as a fallback (e.g. make it an optional dependency of your library that's only imported if node:crypto isn't there).
